# Is this a good way to use the response from the first call to use it on the second?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am new to Reactjs and i wanted to link 2 requests together. It works but i wanted to know if there was a better way to do this.

Here's my code

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [data2, setData2] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(api, config)
        .then(res => {
            setData(res.data);
        })
        .then(res => {
            let id = data.compte.id;
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/compte/${id}`, config).then(res => {
                setData2(res.data);
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}, []);
```

Comment: No, the code in your question will definitely throw an error. The second `res` is `undefined`. Fix that (perhaps by just removing the second `.then` completely) and sure, the code is reasonable

Comment: not returning the inner `axios.get` call seems like an issue. You're not error-handling if the call to `/compte/${id}` failes

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake, i forgot to remove the "res". I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close but there's a few problems:

1. You don't return anything from your Promise handlers, so some of your variables are undefined.
2. (related to #1) There's basically never a reason to have nested `.then`s
3. As collinD points out in the comments you aren't `.catch`ing any errors on the second call.
4. Instead of `console.log` for errors you probably want `console.error`.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [data2, setData2] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(api, config)
        .then(res => {
            setData(res.data);
            let id = res.data.compte.id;
            return axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/compte/${id}`, config)
        })
        .then(setData2)
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })
}, []);
```

This whole thing would arguably look cleaner with `async`/`await`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [data2, setData2] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  const fn = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(api, config);
      setData1(res);
      const id = res.data.compte.id;
      const res2 = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/compte/${id}`, config);
      setData2(res2);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  fn();
}, []);
```

Comment: It looks way better with `async`/`await` like you did. About the #3, is it okay to do nested `try`/`catch` ?

Comment: @Yasuraka you can if you want to handle the two error cases differently, but the existing try/catch will handle any rejected promise in it's try block as long as it's `await`ed.